# Is cloud functions deployment down?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I tried to deploy a few cloud functions. It just gets stuck.

I tried to deploy with gcloud cli and also using GUI.

Used command:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs10 --verbosity=debug --log-http --region=us-central1
```

I tried to deploy to different regions. Same result.

logs:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.functions.deploy] with arguments: [--log-http: "true", --region: "europe-west1", --runtime: "nodejs10", --trigger-http: "True", --verbosity: "debug", NAME: "hello"]
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/expando-eve/locations/europe-west1/functions/hello?alt=json
method: GET
== headers start ==
Authorization: --- Token Redacted ---
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 0
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk x_Tw5K8nnjoRAqULM9PFAC2b gcloud/254.0.0 command/gcloud.functions.deploy invocation-id/fe5896cf229244f39b51b573c1477967 environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.16 term/xterm-256color (Linux 5.0.0-21-generic)
== headers end ==
== body start ==

== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
cache-control: private
content-length: 158
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 25 Jul 2019 14:35:39 GMT
server: ESF
status: 404
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Function hello in region europe-west1 in project expando-eve does not exist",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}

-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.258 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
INFO: Using ignore file at [./.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: Skipping file [./.gitignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [./.gcloudignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [./.idea/.gitignore]
INFO: Using ignore file at [./.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: Skipping file [.gitignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.gcloudignore]
DEBUG: Skipping file [.idea/.gitignore]
=======================
==== request start ====
uri: https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/expando-eve/locations/europe-west1/functions:generateUploadUrl?alt=json
method: POST
== headers start ==
Authorization: --- Token Redacted ---
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 2
content-type: application/json
user-agent: google-cloud-sdk x_Tw5K8nnjoRAqULM9PFAC2b gcloud/254.0.0 command/gcloud.functions.deploy invocation-id/5d5a3c8af0f1441f99b9ad553e5cbbc2 environment/None environment-version/None interactive/True from-script/False python/2.7.16 term/xterm-256color (Linux 5.0.0-21-generic)
== headers end ==
== body start ==
{}
== body end ==
==== request end ====
---- response start ----
-- headers start --
-content-encoding: gzip
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"
cache-control: private
content-length: 122
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 25 Jul 2019 14:37:40 GMT
server: ESF
status: 503
transfer-encoding: chunked
vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 0
-- headers end --
-- body start --
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}

-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 120.153 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
DEBUG: Response returned status 503, retrying
DEBUG: Retrying request to url https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/expando-eve/locations/europe-west1/functions:generateUploadUrl?alt=json after exception HttpError accessing <https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/expando-eve/locations/europe-west1/functions:generateUploadUrl?alt=json>: response: <{'status': '503', 'content-length': '122', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'server': 'ESF', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private', 'date': 'Thu, 25 Jul 2019 14:37:40 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43,39"', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

I would expect that api would be available.

Comment: There's an incident reported for that in the Google Cloud Status Dashboard yes: https://status.cloud.google.com//incident/cloud-functions/19005

Comment: Generically, this link provides an overview of GCP status ... https://status.cloud.google.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was an issue from 25-07-2019 06:41 to 25-07-2019 18:23 PT, now it's solved you can check the status of Google Cloud Products at the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/)